# 2 NSDates that should be equal aren't?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, equality

I'm using the JSON library from Stig Brautaset(http://code.google.com/p/json-framework) and I need to serialize an NSDate. I was considering converting it into a string before JSONifying it, however, I ran into this weird behavior:

Why aren't these NSDates considered equal?

```
NSDate *d = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *dd = [NSDate dateWithString:[d description]];

NSLog(@"%@", d);
NSLog(@"%@", dd);
if( [d isEqualToDate:dd] ){
    NSLog(@"Yay!");
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you describe the original date object you lose some sub-second precision from the original object — in other words, [`-description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/description) shaves off fractional seconds, and returns

> A string representation of the receiver in the international format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM`, where `±HHMM` represents the time zone offset in hours and minutes from GMT

When you create a new date object based on the description, you get it in whole seconds because the string is only precise to a whole second. So [`-isEqualToDate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate:) returns `NO` because there is a difference of a fraction of a second between your two date objects, which it's sensitive to.

> This method detects sub-second differences between dates. If you want to compare dates with a less fine granularity, use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` to compare the two dates.

So you'd do something like this instead (`NSTimeInterval` measures in seconds):

```
if ([d timeIntervalSinceDate:dd] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Yay!");
}
```

Comment: `-timeIntervalSinceDate:` was returning non-zero when my two dates were apparently 0.0005 seconds apart. I ended up comparing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", d]` for each date.

Comment: NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate return an NSTimeInterval which is a Double value which may be smaller as a second. I this case i suggest to check like this `[d timeIntervalSinceDate:dd] < 1' If 1 seconed to vague  us a smaller number e.g. 0.1

Answer (score 2):

isEqualToDate detects subseconds differences between dates, but the description method does not include subseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Because they're not equivalent:

```
NSDate *d = [NSDate date];
NSDate *dd = [NSDate dateWithString:[d description]];
NSLog(@"%f", [d timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
NSLog(@"%f", [dd timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

Produces:

```
2011-04-28 11:58:11.873 EmptyFoundation[508:903] 325709891.867788
2011-04-28 11:58:11.874 EmptyFoundation[508:903] 325709891.000000
```

In other words, the `+dateWithString:` method does not maintain sub-second precision.