# Comparing equal NSDates is returning them as not equal

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

I take a date and make a new pointer of it, then compare it to another date, of equal value. It reports this back as being the same date, but claims them not to be a match:

```
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[date1 timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSLog(@"date 2: %@", date2);
NSLog(@"date 3: %@", date3);
NSLog(@"equal: %i", [date2 isEqualToDate:date3]);
```

This is the NSLog:

```
date 2: 2013-03-15 11:12:24 +0000
date 3: 2013-03-15 11:12:24 +0000
equal: 0
```

Any idea why these aren't returning as equal?

Comment: u can check the two nsdates with this [date3 compare:date2] ==NSOrderedSame

Comment: how date3 gets value?

Comment: your precision is probably insufficient.  Check [date2 timeIntervalSince1970] == [date3 timeIntervalSince1970]

Comment: This answer explains it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823486/2-nsdates-that-should-be-equal-arent

Comment: I used same code, and getting equal : 1

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2]; // comparing two dates
switch (result) {
  case NSOrderedAscending:
    InfoLog(@"date1 is less");
    break;
  case NSOrderedDescending:
    InfoLog(@"date1 is greater");
    break;
  case NSOrderedSame:
    InfoLog(@"same date");
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar         = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date2];
NSDate *date2New             = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
components                   = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date3];
NSDate *date3New             = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

if([date2New isEqualToDate:date3New])
{
   //do stuffs
}
```

I think the issue in your code is, the isEqualToDate: will check for exactly same date (sub-second difference will also cause the condition to fail)

According to [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **isEqualToDate:**
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object is an
>   NSDate object and exactly equal the receiver.
>   `- (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate`
>
> ***Parameters***
>
> **anotherDate**
>
> ```
> The date to compare with the receiver.
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> YES if the anotherDate is an NSDate object and is exactly equal to the
>   receiver, otherwise NO.
>
> ***Discussion***
>
> **This method detects sub-second differences between dates. If you want
>   to compare dates with a less fine granularity, use
>   timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the two dates**.

Answer (score 0):

It compares with microseconds also so it gives the value like 0.
   `timeIntervalSinceDate:`this method used  for the dates being within a range of microseconds, seconds etc.

Answer (score 0):

`date2` and `date3` are off by milliseconds.

to compare then using second precision do this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date2 toDate:date3 options:0];
if (comps.second == 0) {
    //do something
}
```